# Get server-side date and add class using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, server-side

Please bear with me. So I have an html list that goes like

- Jan - Mar 2014
- Apr - May 2014
- Jul - Sep 2014
- Oct - Dec 2014

I need to get server-side date (do I need php to do this or just jquery), and add the class "active" to the appropriate `<a>` tag.
So if date is September, I need to add class to the `<a>` tag that says jul - sep 2014.
How can I do all this using jquery or with php? do I need to use ids to find which `<a>` tag to add the class to?
Please help! Thank you.

see my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wolverene/wrj65opk/7/

Comment: Get the server-side date when loading the page or through an AJAX request, and set it in javascript (or directly when sending the page if that is acceptable). You should try to write some JS code so you have a specific programming problem to ask about.

Comment: You need to get the server time by an ajax request. Then use the recieved data to do an regex check and extract the current mouth. Use JS switch case to calc whether its "Jan-Mar"... and finally select the argument and apply .addClass("active").